# Remove duplicates text in a column

Tags: bash, text, duplicates

i have a file.csv with space separator;

```
name1 A
name1 B
name1 C
name2 A
name2 B
name2 C
```

my desidered output is:

```
name1 A
      B
      C
name2 A
      B
      C
```

i have used the sort -u e unique -u command, but not work.
Maybe it's not the right commands?

Comment: A CSV file may contain newlines in the cells: `c1 c2 "c3_line1\nc3_line2"`. If the cells in your file may have newline characters, then you need a CSV parser, and the shell commands such as awk, sed, sort are not appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk '{if(x!=$1)x=$1;else gsub(/./," ",$1)}1' file

name1 A
      B
      C
name2 A
      B
      C
```

Comment: it works, but do not understand the "gsub"?
thank you

Comment: It replaces every character in the first field with a space, ensuring that the correct indentation is preserved